# Acidic nature of benzene and other alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Is benzene acidic? It has $sp^2$ hybridization so doen it mean that it is acidic in nature? Are alkenes acidic?

Answer (score 5):

A sp<sup>2</sup>-hybridized carbon is more electronegative than an sp<sup>3</sup>-hybridized carbon, and you would expect it to be more acidic.

Experiments support this prediction.  Benzene has a pK<sub>a</sub> of ~ 43, compared to alkanes, which have a pK<sub>a</sub> of ~ 50.  You can prepare lithioaromatics from bromo/iodoaromatics and butyllithium via metal-halogen exchange.

The situation with alkenes is slightly more complicated; the pK<sub>a</sub> of vinylic protons is in the same ballpark as of aromatic protons, but allylic protons are slighty more acidic.

Consult [any](http://evans.rc.fas.harvard.edu/pdf/evans_pKa_table.pdf) of the [usual](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/pkatable/) pK<sub>a</sub> tables on the web.